# Unable to line up text next to image when text wraps to second row with flex

Tags: html, css, text, flexbox

I need help.  Been trying for a few days to get the text to wrap up properly using flex.  Nothing seems to work.  flex-wrap:nowrap; and flex-direction:row; text:wrap; I would like to have the image then the text wrapped so it is even with the text on the other line like. Plus also control the spacing between the rows.  I even tried adding the `<div`>  but I believe the issue is with my css code just haven't been able to figure out the right combination to fix my issue.

```
 <div class="image"><img src="images/trash.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Landfill" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                        <div class="text">
                            Landfill
                        </div>
    </div>
```

image  Target Property
image  Drinking Water Well
image  Hazardous Waste
Generator
[image]

```
div class="mb-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
        <div class="map-wrapper">
            <div class='map-container'id="map"></div>
            <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="legend">
            <h2> Legend </h2>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img  style="vertical-align:left" src="images/house_icon.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Pin that indicates target property"> 
                        <span style="vertical-align:left">Target Property</span>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/well.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Waterwell"> 
                        <span>Drinking Water Well</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img style="vertical-align:left" src="images/hazardous.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Hazardous waste sight"> 
                        <span>Hazardous Waste Generator</span>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                <button id='center-button'>Center</button>
</div>

<!-- Map End -->

    legend{
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow-y:auto; 
    padding:10px; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom:20px;
    right:20px;
    width:220px;
    height:260px;
    max-height:100%;
    z-index:4;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
    
    .legend img {
    padding-right: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .legend span {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex: 0 0 0%;
    padding-right: 2px;
    }
    
    .legend h2{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone help your tips work.

```
.image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
 }

    <div class="image">
                        <img style="float: left; padding-right: 6px;" src="images/house_icon.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Pin that indicates target property"> 
                        <span>Target Property</span>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `display:flex` to your `image` class

```css
.image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 175px;
}

img {
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://toppng.com//public/uploads/preview/warning-vectors-and-icons-warning-svg-icon-11553508662kccnngsukp.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Hazardous waste sight">
  <span>Hazardous Waste Generator</span>
</div>
```

Comment: When I add the padding: .5em it is shrinking my image and also the wording isn't right.

Comment: The padding in my example is not necessary it's just to give  the image some room. And "isn't right" is vague at best. In what way is it not right?

Answer (score -1):

```
You can try adding display : flex to image class. 
Checkout code pen solution.
https://codepen.io/gauravshankar/pen/KKWvjzj 

You need to make changes whatever is written between the comment - /*  Required Changes*/ 
.image {
  display: flex;
} 

You can also add align-items: center; if you want to align image to the center of text. 

If image is of different size you can provide width to the image. 
final code may be something like this. 
.image {
  display: flex;
align-items: center;
width: 30px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/gauravshankar/pen/KKWvjzj

Comment: Thanks. But I still want For example Target Property to be on one line. Plus to have hazardous waste generator show as.         Hazardous Waste                                                                                  Generator.      Just have Generator wrap to the second line and line up with Hazard.